# How to select inner most div element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>First</p>
        <div>
            <p>Second</p>
            <div>
                <p>Third</p>
                <div>
                    <p>Fourth</p>
                    <p>Fifth</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to change color of the paragraph tags in the inner most div using css.

Ex: Fourth and Fifth should be red and First should be green, Second and Third should be blue

i used

```
div div div p
{
color:red;
}
```

But if again another outer div is added again we need to re write it as

```
div div div div p { color: red};
```

is there any other way to select the inner most div and select the paragraph elements to change the color.

JS fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/FGQHh/

Answer (score 2):

Let me introduce you to **[CLASS and ID](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php)**. This is how we can distinguish the same elements within a page.

This is how your code will be like if you use ID's

**[EXAMPLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/FGQHh/1/)** (with ID's)

**[EXAMPLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/FGQHh/3/)** (with Classes)

HTML

```
<div id="green">
    <p> First </p>
    <div id="blue">
        <p> Second </p>
        <div>
            <p> Third </p>
            <div id="red">
                <p> Fourth </p>
                <p> Fifth </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#red
{
    color:red;
}
#blue
{
    color:blue;
}
#green
{
    color:green;
}
```

Comment: Rather use `class` instead of `ID`. It's reusable!

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan  i think ID's is better to get someone started in the idea, for some reason beginners can't get the class option, but yeah +1 for reusability in classes :)

Comment: @Thanos not true, the first thing I learned in my life were ID and 5seconds later `classes`. So I think most of us. Exactly suggesting in the start to use `ID` leads to questions here where people give examples of copy-pasted elements with same `ID` without knowing the case of their issue. After a first look it's almost obvious that the OP is about to create a tree-list. In such case he might end up having multiple `.second` etc... After all the most common thing in web design is to have custom color classes like e.g. `.red` or `.bg_red`, all one has to do is add that class to any element

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan yeah noticed that and just added an example with classes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just assign a class?

```
<div class="test">
<p> Fourth </p>
<p> Fifth </p>
</div>

.test p{
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Yes i told that by using id and class we can achieve but i was asked whether it is possible to do without id or class using javascript

Comment: @CoderKnowledge you know jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the solution here

http://jsfiddle.net/ramanmandal2/ReAVn/

```
var element;
length=document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;

for(i=0;i<length;i++){
element=document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i];
hasDivChild=false;
for(j=0;j<element.childNodes.length;j++){
    if(element.childNodes[j].nodeName=="DIV") hasDivChild=true;
}
if(!hasDivChild) element.style.border="1px solid red"; //Bordering red to the   innermost div tag
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add css only to inner most div child of a div , you can use following code:

```
   div:not(div)
   {
     color:red;
   }
```

Comment: `div:not(div)` will not select anything. Maybe you wanted `div:not(:has(div))`, but that works in jQuery but not CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "#outerdiv";
while($(s + " >div ").size() > 0)
    s += " > div";
    $(s).css("color", "#FF0000");
```

**OR**

```
$('#outerdiv div:last').css({color: "red"});
```

**OR**

```
$('body div:last').css({color: "red"});
```

**HTMl**

```
<body id="outerdiv">
    <div>
        <p> First </p>
        <div>
            <p> Second </p>
            <div>
                <p> Third </p>
                <div>
                    <p> Fourth </p>
                    <p> Fifth </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FGQHh/5/)**

Comment: I would give you a +1 if you used `$('#outerdiv div:last').css({color: "red"});` tho I see only the `javascript` tag, not the `jquery`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you for the new knowledge. I will improve my answer.